# label value inside another label

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, label

There is a label label_query which contains the SOQL query say **'Select name from Account where recordtypeId = 'value coming from another label'**. In another label is stored recordtypeid. Now to use this recordtype label in label_query what one needs to do ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: You should not really store queries in labels imo.

Comment: I just take this as an example for my question. My concern is can we use a label value inside another label ?

Answer (score 0):

use separate label for query and where.

```
String query = Label.query + ' ' + label.where; 
system.debug(query);
system.debug(database.query(query));
```

Comment: i want value of one label inside another label. Can we do so ?